# Ruby equivalent of Java's Collections.unmodifiableList and Collections.unmodifiableMap

Tags: java, ruby, collections, unmodifiable

Is there a equivalent in the Ruby standard API for Java's `Collections.unmodifiableList` and `Collections.unmodifiableMap`?

Comment: You probably should tag ruby first, and explain what those do.

Comment: You may use `freeze` method. See http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/mutable_and_immutable_objects.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-freeze) API:

> Prevents further modifications to obj. A RuntimeError will be raised
>   if modification is attempted. There is no way to unfreeze a frozen
>   object. See also Object#frozen?.
>
> This method returns self.
>
> ```
> a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
> a.freeze
> a << "z"
> ```
>
> produces:
>
> ```
> prog.rb:3:in `<<': can't modify frozen array (RuntimeError)
>  from prog.rb:3
> ```

You can also use the [hamster](https://github.com/hamstergem/hamster) gem for other immutable data structures.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create, for example, unmodifiable (immutable) list:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.freeze
```